# Naked domain support for Azure Websites

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

From the looks of it the new [Azure Websites](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/06/07/meet-the-new-windows-azure.aspx) Feature still does not support hosting them under a naked domain such as example.com instead of www.example.com. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nageeb You cannot use a CNAME to map to a naked domain. That's the problem.

Comment: Looks like I posted before I thought.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Websites have now released support for naked domains. Websites that are run on Shared or Reserved instances does support naked domains through an A record. Domain management is available through the Azure management portal.

**Update 2012-10-21:**

I previously stated that free instances could rely on CNAME to redirect a subdomain to their free Azure-website, but this appear to be incorrect, at least at the moment. Doing a CNAME to your Azure-website will result in an HTTP 404, as reported by *MemeDeveloper* in his comment.

<strike>However, if you run your website on a Free instance, you are still limited to CNAME, so for those websites naked domains are not possible.</strike>

**Update:**

As *MemeDeveloper* suggest in his comment, there are web services you can use that will take your naked-domain `example.com` and redirect it to `www.example.com` for you. For your `www` subdomain you could then have a CNAME to your Azure-URL.

Not as clean as a simple A record that is available for your paid websites, but a workaround for your free sites.

Comment: Not true, the naked domain is possible, just not through pure DNS. Yes MS don't have the solution built in for free instances due to changing IPs, but no reason you can't do this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13494443/661584

Comment: Sorry to be clear, the user won't see the naked domain in the browser. they'll end up on the www subdomain obviously, but if you just need to be able to get to the site using the naked domain the above will help.

Comment: @MemeDeveloper Thanks for that, updated my answer with some additional info.

Comment: @Christofer Eliasson thanks... I'm interested, I just tried a CNAME to a free instance, and getting 404. This sentence is ambiguous "if you configure your web sites for shared or reserved mode, you can map your web site to your own domain name" I am wondering if you can use CNAMEs with Free? Can you confirm. I get 404, but maybe missing something...

Comment: @MemeDeveloper Looking at that sentence I can't say I'm sure it actually will work with a CNAME - as you say, it is ambiguous. I took it for granted that it would be possible to do a CNAME since you get an Azure URL for your free sites, but I might be wrong there. If you get a 404, it sounds like they've done something to prevent it. Have you found any other input to support it?

Comment: Well my CNAME gets me to the right IP for sure, but I see an IIS style 404 think they don't want to give too much away for free ;) which is kind of understandable. Do hope they allow this, can't see a technical issue guess its a commercial decision - but maybe still not set in stone - we can hope.

Comment: @MemeDeveloper Thanks for the additional information, I'll update my answer accordingly. It would indeed be nice with CNAME for free websites as well. I believe Scott GU has said that the free websites should be considered an option for testing your website, but production sites should run on shared or reserved, and I guess for a test-site it doesn't matter what URL you use to access it.

Comment: Sure thing it's a great job Gu's done with Azure - plus the TFSpreview integration is pure joy - its a real offering of course needs a price. Just waiting for fully integrated out-of-the-box DB Proj > SQL Azure deploys / upgrades and I'll be pure cloud 9 and paying won't bother us one bit ;)

Answer (score 3):

The conversations above are a bit dated.  This entry however, comes up at the top of the list when folks are hunting/searching for Azure Naked Domain support.I'd update the answer.

Azure now supplies an IP in shared and > plans, and you can configure a naked domain.

Check out the following articles for more info:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/10/01/mapping-a-naked-url-to-your-azure-web-site-url-with-no-www.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Azure does not support naked domain, because this requires to map definitively an IP address to the domain name. To map a naked domain name, you need a 1 record in the DNS. So, in this case, services like load balancing are more difficult to put in place.

Most registrars provide a way to redirect a naked domain request to another name, through HTTP redirect mechanism. For instance, you could redirect example.com to www.example.com.

Comment: Yes I know that but its still unsatisfying.

Comment: why? I agree its annoying, but what's the essential need. If its 301 then its permanent and performance difference is negligible and SEO is fine. Can't really see a massive issue. Agree naked is nicer, who needs www. but... trying to imagine some serious functional reason why 301 doesn't do the job?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion about this. I don't know what the deal with Websites is, but normal Azure Web Roles provide a virtual IP address that is guaranteed not to change unless you delete a webrole deployment.

You can bind a domain name A-record to that VIP, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg981933.aspx).

In practice, that means that when I want to update my website, I have to do a staging deployment first; and then switch it with the production deployment, and finally delete the staging deployment. The only caveat that I've been aware of, is that you can't do this if you switch your endpoint configuration (not even names).

I'm currently looking if there are same kinds of guarantees for websites, but haven't found appropriate documentation yet.