# How to set up an A-record for Azure hosted website / web role?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

We want to host a website on Windows Azure and it can technically be a *Website* or a *Web role*, we don't particularly care. Is there currently a way to set an A-record for either of them?

It seems that *shared* Websites don't support DNS entries at all and that the *reserved* instances support CNAME only. Do web roles support A-type DNS records?

If not, how real-world deployments on Azure deal with that? For our web site, it is absolutely necessary that it serves both `www.example.com` and `example.com`.

Comment: Think that currently with azure Web Sites : Free = no custom domains, Shared and Reserved = Both A and CNAME possible https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** As of 9.17.2012 it is possible to add an A Record to a [azure-web-sites](/questions/tagged/azure-web-sites) instance, follow the [Configuring a Custom Domain name for a Windows Azure Web Site](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/) instructions on WindowsAzure.com

---

A records are not <strike>possible</strike> suggested, but CNAMEs are.

Steve Marx blogged about [setting up custom domains on windows azure](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure), you'll want to take a look at that.

> There is also [DNSAzure](http://dnsazure.com), I've never tried the service and am simply stating that is a potential option. I do not guarantee it is a supported alternative, nor that it is a valid service.

Comment: The Windows Azure website clearly states that A-records are possible for hosted services (even though CNAME is preferred): https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/

Comment: Steve Marx's blog post on that is great, helped me out in 2010 but now v out of date. Much has changed as per link in your update.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment you cannot use A records or naked domains for Web Sites. For Web Roles this is possible, but there's a caveat.

Each time you deploy for the first time to an empty slot (production/staging) you will get a reserved IP address, and you'll keep this until you delete that deployment. So, you can use A records on that IP address, but beware never to delete it or you'll lose the IP address.

Quoting the [Windows Azure website](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/):

> Note, however, because the lifetime of the IP address is associated
>   with a deployment, it is important not to delete your deployment if
>   you need the IP address to persist. Conveniently, the IP address of a
>   given deployment slot (production or staging) is persisted when using
>   the two upgrade mechanisms in Windows Azure: VIP swaps and in-place
>   upgrades.

Comment: They are moving quickly in azure land now... you now CAN use A records and hence naked domains in web sites. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12509891/661584

Answer (score 2):

I've been **struggling with exactly this issue**. I have a wildcard CNAME in DNS (route 53) to map everything for

```
*.example.com to example.cloudapp.net
```

All fine. **Except** the **damn naked (root) domain**.

I previously used 301 redirection as I had a dedicated server with a static IP. Simply had an

```
A record for example.com to server IP
```

then in IIS a site with correct bindings with a simple

```
HTTP redirect (permanent 301)
```

Everything was just fine and life was good. Then we got rid of our dedicated server, and suddenly... No sensible way to get naked traffic to the example.cloudapp.net address ! Pain, problems, hours of Googling, hair pulling at how something so simple and so obviously necessary could be such a pain (or cost so much)...

**Then ... about to throw in the towel in dismay and buy some needless hosting / service** ... I stumbled upon the fantastic [wwwizer.com](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect)

And **joy one minute later** all is **sunny again**

Comment: Just to be clear... this is not a DNS solution per-say but if you just need free naked - www redirection... for your cloud app it does the job just fine.

Comment: is that service trustable? (wwwizer.com) because their page looks "old"

Comment: @miguel I didn't have any problems - and often old just means... well old, nothing more. Also maybe made by people NOT money crazed and hence actually less likely to be some kind of scam.

Comment: But you know - things have changed since I posted this. You can use A records now in Azure.

Comment: you can? where? anyway i dont want a  fixed ip, i just want the naked domain to be redirected to the cname www

Comment: @miguel how about https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/10/01/mapping-a-custom-naked-domain-to-your-azure-website-a-url-with-no-www/